# C++ SFINAE in dummy parameter in MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae

I've tried to perform as simple as possible SFINAE overload in order to write several kinds of one `getSize(s)` function: one returns `s.getSize()` and another one `s.GetLength()`, then I'll probably add `s.length()`, etc.

Unfortunately, this code produced strange error on MSVC 2015 Update 3:

Am I missing something, or this is some compiler issue?

```
template <typename T> 
static size_t getSize(const T& string, decltype(&T::size) dummy = nullptr)
{
    return string.size();
}

template <typename T> 
static size_t getSize(const T& string, decltype(&T::GetLength) dummy = nullptr)
{
    return static_cast<size_t>(string.GetLength());.
}

assert(SpellCheck::getSize(CString("123")) == 3);       // .GetLength()
assert(SpellCheck::getSize(std::string("123")) == 3);   // .size()
```

> error C2572: 'SpellCheck::getSize': redefinition of default argument:
>   parameter 1
>
> error C2535: 'size_t SpellCheck::getSize(const T &,unknown-type)':
>   member function already defined or declared
>
> error C2672: 'SpellCheck::getSize': no matching overloaded function
>   found
>
> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'size_t
>   SpellCheck::getSize(const T &,unknown-type)' : note:
>   'T=ATL::CStringT>>'

As far as I understand, `getSize(CString())` will differ from `getSize(std::string())` at least by `dummy` pointer type, so their signatures will be different and overloading resolution should work fine.

Can anyone suggest me why it complains about some `unknown-type`, please?

I managed to let it work by this strange construction:

```
template <typename T> 
static auto getSize(const T& string) -> decltype(string.size())
{ 
    return string.size(); 
}

template <typename T> 
static auto getSize(const T& string) -> decltype(static_cast<size_t>(string.GetLength()))
{ 
    return static_cast<size_t>(string.GetLength()); 
}
```

Surprisingly, with such auto it works fine.

I've also checked this code on gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3), both variants works fine. Of course, I've also implemented CString for gcc in order to test instantiation:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <atlstr.h>
#else
struct CString
{
    CString(const char*)  {}
    int GetLength() const { return 3; }.
};
#endif
```

So, please suggest me, whether I'm missing something or first example triggers some MS-specific issue?

EDIT: simplified second solution

Comment: IIRC MSVS's expression SFINAE doesn't exist or is severely lacking.

Comment: ... until the most recent versions where two-pass template parsing is done. MSVC 2015 is not enough though :(

Comment: I've missed that there is 2 "types" of SFINAE, thanks. Looks pretty close to what they have implemented in 2017: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/

Comment: Interesting that even 2015 works well with auto return type deduction: `template <typename T> static auto getSize(const T& string) -> decltype(string.size()) { ... }`. So I think that's my the easiest implementation of getSize().